# Call ItemCommand on Page_Load

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Basically, I have a repeater. When I click one of the rows of the repeater, I want to handle `ItemCommand` first then `Page_Load`. Is there any way to achieve it? If not, is there any way to call `ItemCommand` event on `Page_Load`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to handle ItemCommand first then Page_Load

No, this is not possible. ASP.NET page life cycle calls Page_Load first and then executes event handlers.

> If not, is there any way to call ItemCommand event on Page_Load

Well, you can call `ItemCommand` handler inside the `Page_Load` explicitly. To get the event details (source and argument) you can use request parameters:

```
// you most likely know the source control that fired the event, right?
string control = Page.Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"];    
// arguments of the event - you might need some parsing though, not sure about their format
string args = Page.Request.Params["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
```

However in first place you should reevaluate your overall approach - are you sure this is the right thing to do? ASP.NET was designed this way for a reason, maybe you should find a more conventional way of doing things

Answer (score -1):

use the Repeater.ItemCommand Event

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcommand(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Repeater.ItemCommand always called after Page_Load. What I wanted to achieve is how to reach ItemCommand before Page_Load. However as @Andrei said, it's not possible.